# Safe and correct way to reload data on angularjs ($timeout)

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I use this code to safe work with `$timeout` :

```
        $scope.intervalFunction = function () {
            setTimeout(function () {
                //DO
                console.log('refresh');
                if ($scope.currentNode) {
                    $scope.intervalFunction();
                }
            }, 5000)
        };

        function setTimeout(fn, delay) {
            var promise = $timeout(fn, delay);
            var deregister = $scope.$on('$destroy', function () {
                $timeout.cancel(promise);
            });
            promise.then(deregister);
        }

        $scope.intervalFunction();
```

it is correct?

Comment: This could work, but I would use another name for the `setTimeout`, because you might get confused because it is a native javascript function

Comment: Another thing, I would make `promise` a controller variable, and the `$scope.$on("$destroy"` also, because you register a new destroy call on each executed timeout

Answer (score 1):

There are a few optimizations here, if it is always the same function that needs to be executed in the timeout:

```
var refreshTimeout;

$scope.intervalFunction = function () {
    // Assign to refreshTimeout, so it can be cancelled on the destroy of the scope
    refreshTimeout = $timeout(function() {
        console.log('refresh');
        if ($scope.currentNode) {
            $scope.intervalFunction();
        }
    }, 5000)
};

$scope.intervalFunction();

// Only one timeout to destroy
// Though I don't think this is even necessary, because probably
// the timeout gets cancelled anyway on the destruction of the scope
$scope.$on('$destroy', function () {
    if (refreshTimeout)        
        refreshTimeout.cancel();
});
```

**EDIT**

According to [this](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2548-don-t-forget-to-cancel-timeout-timers-in-your-destroy-events-in-angularjs.htm) article, you do need to destroy the timeout yourself :)