# Set a timeout on jQuery .load() callback

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm loading an image with handlers for valid images and invalid ones:

```
$('<img/>')  
.attr('src',$scope.newAssetData.newAssetUrl)
.load(validImage)
.error(invalidImage);
```

I would like to set a timeout on load. Meaning, if an image takes more than t time to load, then do something (for example, go to the invalidImage handler).

Any ideas how to do it?

Thank you,
Mila

Comment: Maybe this topic will hell you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30799521/safe-and-correct-way-to-reload-data-on-angularjs-timeout

Comment: Your question shows little research. Try researching Promises or $.deferred if you are using jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to use a timeout this way for example:

```
var delay = 1000, /* if image takes more than one second to load, call error handler */
    $img = $('<img/>').load(validImage)
        .error(invalidImage)
        .attr('src', $scope.newAssetData.newAssetUrl); /* set src after relevant events to hanlde older browsers cached src */
setTimeout(function () {
    if (!this.complete || typeof this.naturalWidth == "undefined" || this.naturalWidth == 0) {
        $(this).off('load');
        invalidImage.call(this);
    }
}.bind($img[0]), delay);
```

Comment: Thank you, this seems to be working great! But what I don't understand is how 'this' in the setTimeout function is the correct object. For me it's just a magic now.

Comment: `.bind($img[0])` is setting context to relevant element in setTimeout callback. Search DOC regarding javascript bind, call and apply methods

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you *can* set a timeout directly on `.load()`.

However, if you want to load images asynchronously then you could write the request out the long way, *i.e.*, using `.ajax()`, then you *can* set a timeout.

According to the documentation for `.load()` "it has an implicit callback function", so you'd have to populate this yourself

For example:

```
$.ajax({
    url: [image src],
    timeout: [in milliseconds],
    type: "GET",
    success: function(response) {
        // I'm not sure what you'll be getting as your response
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    }
});
```

Here's the [full documentation for `.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

Comment: No here `load(handler);` is shorthand for `.on('load', handler);`  https://api.jquery.com/load-event/

Comment: Point taken - I'll edit my post. But she's still loading images asynchronously so my suggestion is still valid.

Comment: `loading images asynchronously` I don't really understand what it means here in OP context's question?!

Comment: @A.Wolff I guess this fact is irrelevant, I'll remove it. I'll try your solution from above.